# combine multiple arrays so that there are a variety of options

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

So let's say I have this array:

```
    "variants": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "color",
        "item_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:19",
        "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:19",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "red",
                "variant_id": 5,
                "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:21",
                "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:21"
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "blue",
                "variant_id": 5,
                "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:21",
                "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:21"
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "green",
                "variant_id": 5,
                "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22",
                "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "size",
        "item_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:19",
        "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:19",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "small",
                "variant_id": 6,
                "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22",
                "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22"
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "medium",
                "variant_id": 6,
                "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22",
                "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22"
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "name": "large",
                "variant_id": 6,
                "created_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22",
                "updated_at": "2018-11-02 15:08:22"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how would you go about combining all of the possibilities so that i'd have:
red small, red medium, red large, blue small, blue medium, blue large, green small, green medium, green large.  Also the arrays would not necessarily always be the same sizes.

This project is being written in PHP specifically using the laravel framework

Comment: Well just create a foreach on first criteria and a second foreach on the second criteria. Or is the question about multiple criteria? If so use a recoursive function iterating over each crieteria(for each value in the criteria) and for each iteration call itself for the next criteria.

Comment: I just cannot figure out how to even loop over it.  I mean let's say there are 10 different variants each with 3-7 options, how could I get every single possiblity?  I'm looking into the map methods with laravel collections but I just cannot see the big picture ofr something as big as what I just described.

Comment: You're trying to produce the cartesian product. If this is output from your database, you can probably do this with the query builder. See crossJoin here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

Answer (score 2):

To accommodate for multiple variants:

```
function getVariants($obj)
{
    $variant = array_shift($obj["variants"]); // we use the variants as a stack
    $results = array(); // we will store the results here
    foreach($variant["options"] AS $k=>$v) // we iterate the current variants
    {
        if(count($obj["variants"]) > 0) // if we have more variants still
        {
            $sub = getVariants($obj); // we call getVariants to build next level
            foreach($sub AS $sub_v) // iterate over the results of the child level
            {
                // concatenate whatever came from children to the current names
                $results[] = $v["name"]." ".$sub_v; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $results[] = $v["name"]; // this is the last variant so we just add the names.
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

This should work with any depth of combinations needed.

What this code does it use the variants as a stack processing the variant and then if the stack is longer still calling itself to do the same on the next level. Each level returns an array of themselves and their children if any.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: so I walked through your code last night and it's slick as heck.  Thank you so much.  I appreciate the comments too, it helped out immensely.